# I am trying solve "Performance limited due to" issues from powermetrics

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

My MacBook sometimes crashes. I think this is due to the battery overheating even though I've just changed the battery to a new one and had my Mac cleaned. This is what I get when I type `sudo powermetrics` and look for performance limits. Is there something I should or can do to improve my performance?

```
Performance Limited Due to:
**CPU LIMIT MAX_TURBO_LIMIT**

**CPU LIMIT TURBO_ATTENUATION**

CPU/GPU Overlap: 0.26%
Cores Active: 43.63%
GPU Active: 0.40%
Avg Num of Cores Active: 0.88

Core 0 C-state residency: 67.31% (C3: 1.26% C6: 0.00% C7: 66.05% )

CPU 0 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 923.84/452.45] [< 32 us: 180.11/139.06] [< 64 us: 196.04/310.60] [< 128 us: 276.13/401.45] [< 256 us: 217.16/187.08] [< 512 us: 151.02/133.09] [< 1024 us: 51.60/129.70] [< 2048 us: 14.15/155.00] [< 4096 us: 5.18/95.83] [< 8192 us: 0.40/11.56] [< 16384 us: 0.20/0.00] [< 32768 us: 0.00/0.00] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 71.12% (1849.05 Mhz)

CPU 1 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 2161.86/457.43] [< 32 us: 6.18/169.55] [< 64 us: 7.17/275.14] [< 128 us: 3.19/414.60] [< 256 us: 0.40/273.94] [< 512 us: 0.00/186.88] [< 1024 us: 0.00/123.52] [< 2048 us: 0.00/124.12] [< 4096 us: 0.00/110.77] [< 8192 us: 0.00/40.64] [< 16384 us: 0.00/2.19] [< 32768 us: 0.00/0.00] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 74.61% (1939.76 Mhz)

Core 1 C-state residency: 69.93% (C3: 2.97% C6: 0.00% C7: 66.96% )

CPU 2 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 1178.45/469.19] [< 32 us: 132.69/129.50] [< 64 us: 145.84/308.81] [< 128 us: 161.38/432.53] [< 256 us: 167.35/180.50] [< 512 us: 118.54/117.75] [< 1024 us: 66.34/90.25] [< 2048 us: 9.56/129.10] [< 4096 us: 4.58/102.40] [< 8192 us: 1.00/25.30] [< 16384 us: 0.00/0.40] [< 32768 us: 0.00/0.00] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 70.80% (1840.87 Mhz)

CPU 3 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 1756.02/440.70] [< 32 us: 6.18/184.29] [< 64 us: 7.37/236.69] [< 128 us: 2.79/263.58] [< 256 us: 0.60/185.48] [< 512 us: 0.00/137.07] [< 1024 us: 0.00/89.06] [< 2048 us: 0.00/85.47] [< 4096 us: 0.00/79.29] [< 8192 us: 0.00/62.16] [< 16384 us: 0.00/8.97] [< 32768 us: 0.00/0.20] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 78.33% (2036.52 Mhz)

Core 2 C-state residency: 71.90% (C3: 3.41% C6: 0.00% C7: 68.49% )

CPU 4 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 1059.91/329.53] [< 32 us: 100.41/84.87] [< 64 us: 125.12/246.65] [< 128 us: 118.54/378.74] [< 256 us: 152.41/202.62] [< 512 us: 77.50/136.07] [< 1024 us: 28.09/83.88] [< 2048 us: 31.28/97.42] [< 4096 us: 1.79/94.24] [< 8192 us: 0.40/39.65] [< 16384 us: 0.20/1.99] [< 32768 us: 0.00/0.00] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 72.74% (1891.34 Mhz)

CPU 5 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 1391.63/293.07] [< 32 us: 5.98/122.33] [< 64 us: 4.58/151.22] [< 128 us: 1.99/206.40] [< 256 us: 1.20/178.91] [< 512 us: 0.00/131.89] [< 1024 us: 0.00/94.83] [< 2048 us: 0.20/79.49] [< 4096 us: 0.00/72.12] [< 8192 us: 0.00/63.36] [< 16384 us: 0.00/10.96] [< 32768 us: 0.00/0.80] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 77.51% (2015.14 Mhz)

Core 3 C-state residency: 78.10% (C3: 2.95% C6: 0.00% C7: 75.15% )

CPU 6 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 948.74/258.80] [< 32 us: 84.47/89.06] [< 64 us: 115.16/194.85] [< 128 us: 115.16/321.16] [< 256 us: 113.96/177.12] [< 512 us: 71.72/129.50] [< 1024 us: 23.31/77.10] [< 2048 us: 7.37/87.26] [< 4096 us: 1.20/92.04] [< 8192 us: 0.60/50.21] [< 16384 us: 0.20/4.78] [< 32768 us: 0.20/0.00] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 73.77% (1917.99 Mhz)

CPU 7 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 451.26/43.83] [< 32 us: 5.58/23.51] [< 64 us: 6.97/45.62] [< 128 us: 2.39/53.19] [< 256 us: 0.60/55.98] [< 512 us: 0.40/55.98] [< 1024 us: 0.00/46.22] [< 2048 us: 0.00/31.68] [< 4096 us: 0.00/34.27] [< 8192 us: 0.00/50.80] [< 16384 us: 0.00/17.13] [< 32768 us: 0.00/6.38] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 73.29% (1905.48 Mhz)

Core 4 C-state residency: 86.17% (C3: 0.55% C6: 0.00% C7: 85.63% )

CPU 8 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 589.33/114.56] [< 32 us: 63.16/29.09] [< 64 us: 77.10/89.45] [< 128 us: 75.91/196.64] [< 256 us: 74.71/120.73] [< 512 us: 40.05/110.77] [< 1024 us: 13.15/66.14] [< 2048 us: 5.78/66.54] [< 4096 us: 2.99/81.09] [< 8192 us: 0.40/58.37] [< 16384 us: 0.00/7.17] [< 32768 us: 0.00/1.20] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 73.90% (1921.37 Mhz)

CPU 9 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 679.58/107.19] [< 32 us: 4.38/56.58] [< 64 us: 5.38/68.34] [< 128 us: 2.59/96.43] [< 256 us: 0.40/84.47] [< 512 us: 0.20/75.31] [< 1024 us: 0.00/47.82] [< 2048 us: 0.00/34.67] [< 4096 us: 0.00/43.03] [< 8192 us: 0.00/55.19] [< 16384 us: 0.00/16.74] [< 32768 us: 0.00/4.98] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 72.12% (1875.08 Mhz)

Core 5 C-state residency: 91.01% (C3: 0.69% C6: 0.00% C7: 90.32% )

CPU 10 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 474.77/73.12] [< 32 us: 25.90/20.32] [< 64 us: 39.25/70.53] [< 128 us: 45.82/127.71] [< 256 us: 43.83/76.31] [< 512 us: 31.88/75.11] [< 1024 us: 11.36/47.62] [< 2048 us: 3.59/51.20] [< 4096 us: 1.20/58.97] [< 8192 us: 0.40/60.17] [< 16384 us: 0.00/12.95] [< 32768 us: 0.00/3.19] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 72.04% (1873.12 Mhz)

CPU 11 duty cycles/s: active/idle [< 16 us: 46.82/2.79] [< 32 us: 2.39/1.39] [< 64 us: 2.39/2.99] [< 128 us: 1.79/2.39] [< 256 us: 0.80/2.39] [< 512 us: 0.00/2.59] [< 1024 us: 0.00/2.39] [< 2048 us: 0.00/2.39] [< 4096 us: 0.00/2.79] [< 8192 us: 0.00/8.97] [< 16384 us: 0.00/9.56] [< 32768 us: 0.00/5.78] 
CPU Average frequency as fraction of nominal: 72.08% (1874.13 Mhz)
```

Comment: What model of Mac is this, and what OS version? When you say "crashes", do you mean a kernel panic, from which you have to restart, or just an app unexpectedly quitting? I would focus on trying to find the cause of the crashes from the crashlogs and other information, rather than assuming it's overheating.

Comment: It's Mac Book Pro 2019 16 inch
IoS is Ventura 13.5
I am assuming it's because of the heat since the coolers are usually blowing hard and get louder.

Thanks for the answer! I will try to figure out the crash logs.